# Don't know how i can select one option in dropdown excel and write in other cell c# excel

Tags: c#, excel, excel-formula

my excel and c# program is structured in this way, first the excel sheet is created that according to the data that comes from the db, a veryhidden sheet is created where the dropdown list data and the respective id of each dropdown object are , what I need is that in a new formula according to the chosen option I write the id of the chosen object in a separate column.

Currently only the objects of the dropdown list are shown

This is my c#

```
using (var rng = worksheet.Cells["A3:A60003"])
{
 var list = rng.DataValidation.AddListDataValidation();
 mycode...
 list.Formula.ExcelFormula = String.Format("Types!$B$1:$B${0}", markets.Count() > 1   markets.Count().ToString() : "1");                     
}
```

An example of what I want is this

Column A ------------------------------------------------------------- Column B
| MarketID | Market |
| -------- | -------- |
| 1   | Option1   |
| 32   | Option4   |

Comment: The table of previualization got destroyed i can't edit de question sorry

Comment: Do you want to have two columns "|MarketID | Market |" and want "Column A" and "Column B" to be removed?